# Displaying labels near of each bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to place the label (category) for each bar to the right of its bar (as on attached image).
The bar's count is from 1 to 20.
Temporary solution is

```
  options.xAxis.labels.align = 'right';
  options.xAxis.labels.rotation = 90;
  options.xAxis.labels.x = 36;
  options.xAxis.labels.y = 7;
```

But the bars are scaled and its width depends on bar count. So I can't set label position with x and y coordinates, it should be flexible.
How can I solve that?

What I should have http://jsfiddle.net/dvasuta/A8LQC/

This is what happens now, if data is less than I expected 
http://jsfiddle.net/dvasuta/A8LQC/1/

[image]

Comment: did you try giving a fixed width to the bar

Comment: can give your fiddle that will help us to give a better solution

Comment: Added jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd implement it (and what I *think* @SebastianBochan is talking about).  First, disable the category xAxis labels.  Then, in the `load` event of the chart, loop the points of the last series (since this will be the farthest right bar) and add the "category" label using the [Renderer.text method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text%28%29).

```
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function(event){
               var lastSeries = this.series[this.series.length-1];
                for (var i = 0; i < lastSeries.points.length; i++){
                    var point = lastSeries.points[i];
                    var text = this.renderer.text(
                        categories[i], 
                        point.plotX + this.plotLeft + (point.pointWidth * 2) + 5, 
                        this.xAxis[0].height - 5
                    ).attr({
                        zIndex: 5,
                        rotation: 90
                    }).add();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8LQC/3/) demonstrating this approach.  Run it multiple times to see how it handles varying series length.

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

To place the text in between the bars use something like this:

```
        events: {
            load: function(event){

               var lastSeries = this.series[this.series.length-1]; 
               var firstSeries = this.series[0];

               // barSpace is the spacing between the bars
               var barSpace = (firstSeries.points[1].plotX - lastSeries.points[0].plotX) / 2;

               for (var i = 0; i < lastSeries.points.length; i++){
                    var point = lastSeries.points[i];                       
                   var text = this.renderer.text(
                        categories[i], 
                        this.plotLeft + point.plotX + barSpace - 3,  //3 is a fudge factor it should be 1/2 the text height
                        this.xAxis[0].height - 5
                    ).attr({
                        zIndex: 5,
                        rotation: 90
                    }).add();
                    console.log(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NsxKz/5/).

Comment: And one more question. How can I center the labels exactly in the middle between the columns?

Comment: @Castro, in the middle horizontally between the last of the preceeding group and first of the next group?  Or in the middle vertically of the bar?

Comment: in the middle horizontally between the last of the preceding group and first of the next group. I've added groupPadding and            pointPadding. And I have position problems  http://jsfiddle.net/dvasuta/NsxKz/1/

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on the forum, you can use renderer which can get position from last column in each "column group".

Comment: How can I get position from last column in each "column group"?